# Unity2D: Character goes up and down during idle animation

Tags: unity, animation

My character is idling but his feet are changing position during the animation: it seems he's floating. I would like to have the character with his feet stuck.

Video to visualize the issue: https://vimeo.com/568057364

As you can see, the feet are going up and down. I've also tried to animate the collider in order to follow the feet, but that attempt didn't solve the issue.

Comment: There is no info about how you character animation is setup. There can be different causes for that depending on your setup.

Comment: it appears that the problem is in your sprite sheet ... the frames of the idle animation aren't consistently on the bottom edge. Use a tool like Photoshop or Gimp to edit the frames in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the pivot of the images to the bottom. It solved the problem. Before it was set to center.